# swift: in-app purchases

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть несколько in-app purchases в приложении. Я использую этот код:

```
@IBAction func purchaseFull(_ sender: Any) {

        purchase = "purchaseFull"   

        product_id = "purchaseFull"

        print("About to fetch the product...")
        //self.loading.startAnimating()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        // Can make payments
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
            let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            print("Fetching Products");
        }else{
            print("Can't make purchases");
        }
    }

@IBAction func purchase(_ sender: Any) {

        purchase = "purchase"

        product_id = "purchase\(index)"

        print("About to fetch the product...")
        //self.loading.startAnimating()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        // Can make payments
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
            let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            productsRequest.start();
            print("Fetching Products");
        }else{
            print("Can't make purchases");
        }
    }

func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        let count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {
            let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
                print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
                print(validProduct.price)
                buyProduct(product: validProduct);

            } else {
                print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            print("nothing")
        }
    }

    func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
        print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);
        //self.loading.stopAnimating()
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error Fetching product information");
        //self.loading.stopAnimating()
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                      updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    print("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    // Handle the purchase

                    if purchase == "purchase" {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase\(index)")
                    }

                    if purchase == "purchaseFull" {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchaseFull")
                    }

                    viewDidLoad()
                    break;
                case .failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;

                case .restored:
                    print("Already Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    // Handle the purchase
                    //UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                    viewDidLoad()
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func restoreAction(_ sender: Any) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
    }

    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {

    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("transactions restored")
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            if prodID == "purchaseFull" {
                print("action for restored")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchaseFull")
            } else if prodID == "purchase0" {
                print("action0")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase0")
            } else if prodID == "purchase1" {
                print("action1")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase1")
            } else if prodID == "purchase2" {
                print("action2")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase2")
            } else if prodID == "purchase3" {
                print("action3")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase3")
            } else if prodID == "purchase4" {
                print("action4")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase4")
            } else if prodID == "purchase5" {
                print("action5")
                queue.finishTransaction(t)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchase5")
            }
        }
        cancelAction((Any).self)
    }
```

Но у меня проблема. Когда я нажимаю на свою кнопку покупки, мой код вызывает эту функцию - paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) и проверка `if else` срабатывает. И мой `Userdefaults` устанавливает `true` для ключа. В результате пользователь разблокирует контент, но не оплачивает покупку. Как это исправить?

**Update**

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                      updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    print("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    // Handle the purchase

                    if purchase == "purchase" {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased\(sectionNumber)\(itemNumber)")
                    }

                    if purchase == "purchaseFull" {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                    }

                    viewDidLoad()
                    break;
                case .failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;

                case .restored:
                    print("Already Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    viewDidLoad()
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func restoreAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновляйте defaults только если в методе

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

отработали эти кейсы: `case .purchased:` или `case .restored:`
Так же желательно сделать валидацию в этих методах для защиты от злоумышленников. Валидацию можно реализовать либо через сервер, либо нативно.
[Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2)
Пример правда описывается на Objective c. Надо будет переписать под swift.

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос. Добавил новый код в **Update**. Он должен выглядеть так?

Comment: В case .purchased: уберите viewDidLoad, и все break кроме default: (это не objective c). Так же в case: restore записывайте параметры в userDefaults (иначе у пользователей которые восстановили покупку не смогут воспользоваться контентом) так-же как вы делали это в case .purchased:. В так-же finishTransaction прописывайте в кейсах в самом конце.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865674/swift-загрузка-файла-и-показ-прогресса